# Can i make the children of my grid layout group not follow the hierarchy? (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

Probably a stupid question but anyway: I have a grid layout for my inventory (Unity 2D 2020) and I would like it so when I pick up an item the inventory displays the items in the order that the gameobject is activated. Currently, if I have an inventory with the hierarchy order as apples, oranges and lemons it looks like this:

apples | oranges | lemons

And if I have no more oranges it looks like this:

apples | lemons

But if pick up an orange at a later time it pushes lemons to third and oranges goes back to being second place instead of being third.

Is there any way to make the grid layout follow the order the items are activated?

I hope this is clear - I suck at explaining things, I'm sorry.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show UI? and Hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you want to create inventory by sorting what items you get first.

In UI setup, you can have Parent `GameObject`, let's call it "Panel", with `Grid Layout Group`component and make prefab of that. Also make another Child `GameObject` of Parent and call it "Container" and make prefab of that too. Lastly you should have prefabs for Apple, Orange and Lemons.

The Panel will always be there in hierarchy but you will `Instantiate` each container when you have new item, for example if you get Apple, you will instantiate apple container inside Panel. Check if you have already instantiated apple container, if not then just add apple gameobject. Do this for other items as well. The instantiated container will always be next in UI.

Sharing some UI setup image I did. (This is only to make you understand)

**UI Setup, showing Panel and Container**

[image: UI Setup, showing Panel and Container]

**Panel Component configuration**

[image: Panel Component configuration]

**Container component configuration**

[image: Container component configuration]

**Output window**

[image: Output window]

Let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: Just use Transform.SetAsLastSibling() for element you activated so element goes to last place.